# Definition of natural representation of quantum group.

Tags: representation-theory, quantum-groups

I have a question about terminology. In [the paper](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pjm/1102365173), a terminology "natural representation" is used. I don't know the precise definition of natural representation. What is the definition of "an $n+1$ dimensional representation of the quantum group $U_q(sl_{n+1})$"? Thank you very much.

Comment: Such a representation is defined on the top page 300 (and bottom of 299).

Comment: @Mathematician42, thanks!